# Memcached and PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, memcached

Okay Im working on a school project. The idea is a HA/LB Setup. The Setup is 3 Webservers running Apache and PHP. A MySQL Cluster Running 4 Datanodes, 2 MySQL Nodes and 2 Management Nodes.

Is there any way to make it so the php-sessions balance across servers without running them from the MySQL Cluster?

In theory I'd have a Memcache server and have Memcache running on each webserver. Is this feasible?

Thank You for your time. (the test enviroment is Virtual Machines before I do proof of concept on physical machines)

Comment: what load balancer do you use ?

Comment: boy, a large school you've got!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that will work.

Think of it this way: Your 3 web servers are threads running on a processor, and your Memcache instance(s) are the memory they are sharing between them. As long as they all have access to it, you should be able to share sessions across multiple web servers.

Disclaimer: I have not tried this, I am commenting solely on the theory behind it.

Comment: Okay the real question is the php5-memcached have the availablity to failover to another server or should i write a c++ that runs locals and switchs to anotehr server?

Comment: here is a patch that deals with memcached replication http://repcached.lab.klab.org/ but idealy you're app/setup should work if memcached servers go down .

Comment: well the idea is use the memcache server as primary. if it to goes down the web servers take up the slack. if all memcache sessions go down i imagine the site will be down completely.

Comment: "Failover may occur at any stage in any of the methods, as long as other servers are available the request the user won't notice" http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want to use mysql for the sessions? If you think it will be faster, then I'd suggest you try it out.

4 database server nodes backing 3 webserver nodes? Why do you think you need so much processing at the database tier?

Comment: When done right, you need much more mysql power than webserver frontends.